# React native doesn't display view from other js file

Tags: react-native

Hello everyone i am new to react native i just stared learning.

i am trying with react native , i have studied about it and now i am trying to learn it , This is my first day in this,

I just created react native project and created one js file and write view in that created js and imported in index.android.jd but it display default view

here is the code

index.android.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
AppRegistry,
StyleSheet,
Text,
View
} from 'react-native';
import Compo from './homecomponent'
export default class AwesomeProject extends Component {
render() {
return (
  <Compo/>
);
}
}
```

AppRegistry.registerComponent('AwesomeProject', () => AwesomeProject);

and homecomponent is as follow

```
import {
AppRegistry,
StyleSheet,
Text,
View,
ToolbarAndroid,
TouchableHighlight
} from 'react-native';

export default class homecomponent extends Component
{
render() 
{
    return(

<view style={styles.container}>
    <ToolbarAndroid style={styles.toolbar0}
    title="counter demo"/>
<Text>WOWWWW</Text>
<TouchableHighlight
style={ styles.button} >
  <Text style={styles.buttontext}>increment</Text>
  </TouchableHighlight>
</view>
        );
}
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
container: {
flex: 1,
justifyContent:'center',
alignItems: 'center',

},
button:{
backgroundColor:'deepskyblue',
borderwidth:1,
alignItems:'center',
justifyContent:'center',
alignSelf:'stretch',
height:50,
margin:10,
borderRadius:3
},

buttontext:{
fontSize:20,
color:'#FFF'
},
toolbar: {
  alignSelf: 'stretch',
  height: 50,
  backgroundColor: 'silver',
},
text: {
  fontSize:20,
},
cancelButton: {

  backgroundColor: '#696969',
},
});
```

Please give me the suggesction why the view is not update in android.I stuck on that problem since morning.

Comment: try by changing this line `import Compo from './homecomponent'` to `import homecomponent from './homecomponent';`

Answer (score 0):

import homecomponent from './HomeCompo'

Comment: updated question.but given solution is also not working not working

Answer (score 0):

Do these two following things:

First, in index.android.js file, update your **import Compo from './homecomponent'** to **import homecomponent from './homecomponent'**

Second, in the same file, update your return component inside view. Just Add View and inside that rename the component name as **homecomponent**.